# How to convert solidified plane to cube/rectangle

Tags: modifiers

I took a plane, and applied the "Solidify" modifier to it. 
 Is it possible to convert that to a cube, or rectangle, so that I can manipulate its edges with the bevel tool more easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure to **add** the bevel modifier after the solidify modifier. If you **applied** it, it should work perferctly fine.

[image]